# Design polygon shape using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to design following shape using CSS. I don't want to use svg or canvas for this.

[image]

How can I design it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far as well and explain where you failed, not just ask questions.

Comment: Try out CSS `clip-path`. Here's a generator: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ - and an example matching your shape: http://i.imgur.com/7kmjGTB.png - but note that cross-browser support is a mixed bag (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). Your best bet might be a background image.

Comment: I have created following fiddle for more idea https://jsfiddle.net/fn1qm7h4/

Comment: You need both black and blue borders around this shape? or only black?

Comment: Only blue border with transparent background clipped corners

Comment: Thank you @JonUleis, As clip path not supporting to IE then there is any other way to create this design using before after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide whole background in different parts and draw each with `:before` and `:after` pseudo element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="holder">
     // content will go here...
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(orange, red);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box:after {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  height: 30px;
  content: '';
  right: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.holder:before {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  margin: -10px 14px 0 25px;
  transform: rotate(52deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;      
  background: green;
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  content: '';
  width: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="holder">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit sit amet, dolor sit sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar you are welcome and please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted which solves your problem. This might help others too in looking for similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using 3 `<div>` tags

- initially create a larger div
- then create two smaller div with absolute position and set their background white

```css
#border{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:3px solid #000;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 3px #3dd7cf;
  background:#304e4b;
  border-bottom-width:5px;
  
  }
#triangle{
  position: absolute;
    top: -31px;
    right: 7px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #3dd7cf;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #000;
   z-index:990;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
#sqr{
  position: absolute;
    top: -22px;
    right: -7px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3dd7cf;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #000;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
  }
```

```html
<div id="border"> 
<div id="triangle"></div>
<div id="sqr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for quick help but I am using background image for background, if I make #triangle and #sqr with transparent background then design not looking proper.